# selected option is not getting displayed Angularjs dropdownlist

Tags: angularjs, select

When I am using an object where I have property which has selectedOptions it is not getting displayed in the dropdownlist. However, when I put in scope and select from the object then it displayed. Anyone has any idea why the first one is not working. Here is the plunker link.

http://plnkr.co/edit/XLuXmAmh4F9OobyJhBCW?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);


var model = {
   options : [
    { id: 1, name: 'foo' },
    { id: 2, name: 'bar' },
    { id: 3, name: 'blah' }],
    selectedOption : { id: 1, name: 'foo' }
}

app.value('vm',model);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,vm) {
  $scope.vm =vm;

  $scope.items = [
    { id: 1, name: 'foo' },
    { id: 2, name: 'bar' },
    { id: 3, name: 'blah' }];

  $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[1];
});

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>Select something below</h1>
    <select id="s1" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items"></select>
    <h3>The selected item:</h3>
    <pre>{{selectedItem | json}}</pre>
    <h3>The inner html of the select:</h3>
    <pre id="options" class="prettify html"></pre>


      <select data-ng-options="o.name for o in vm.options" data-ng-model="vm.selectedOption"><option value="">Select one</option></select>
      <pre>{{vm.selectedOption | json}}</pre>


  </body>
```

Comment: How to make this working , I made this working by using selectedoption as id. plnkr.co/edit/XLuXmAmh4F9OobyJhBCW?p=preview But each time when I want to display the selected option name I have call a function to display it. But I do not like that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses strict comparison (`===`) to evaluate if given option is to be selected. It will only if the value of `selectedItem` is **the same** as the option's one. And in JavaScript, if you create two objects of the same structure and try to strictly compare it, they are not the same, i.e.:

```
{a: 1} !== {a: 1}
```

In the second example you're keeping the reference to the original object insted, so it would be like doing this:

```
var obj1 = {a: 1};
var obj2 = obj1;
obj1 === obj2;
```

Comment: So every time when I want selected option name then do I have call a function to filter and show? Like I did here http://plnkr.co/edit/XLuXmAmh4F9OobyJhBCW?p=preview